# How to pass two sql tables as input parameter for r codes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r

I am running r codes in SQL Server. I have two tables in SQL Server database that I would like to pass as input data set into the R code. I can use `@input_data_1` to pass one of the input data set. How can I pass the other table?

I read from [one MSDN help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt793558.aspx) saying that:

> Only one input dataset can be passed as a parameter, and you can
>   return only one dataset. However, you can call other datasets from
>   inside your R code. But I did not find a way to do it yet.

Here is my code related to the question:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'R'  
,@script = N' 
rules_set <- InputDataSet
#rules_set2 <- InputDataSet2 #need to be passed
'
,@input_data_1 = N'SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[[Rules_Set]'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Assuming that you are using Windows, it could be easier to use RODBC to get your input.

Comment: Do you mean like this?  (Yes, I am using Windows)                         EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'R'  
,@script = N'                                                                            library(RODBC)
ch <- odbcConnect("dsn", uid = "sa", pwd = "pass@word1")
input1 <- sqlFetch(ch, "table1")
input2 <- sqlFetch(ch, "table2")'

Comment: I am sorry that the format is messing. I am new to StackOverflow, still learning how to ask question and add comments

Comment: @r.user.05apr         Thank you for your answer. It turns out to be some user credential issues for my situation. Both 'odbcConnect' function in RODBC package and 'RxSqlServerData'  function in RevoScaleR package worked well for me.

Comment: @Y.Li , if you have solved your problem, could you share it please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use R's built in [serialization](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/serialize.html) to accomplish this in the SQL Server 2016. It's definitely verbose, however, it does work.

Example, setup two separate input temp tables ([they cannot be table variables, unfortunately](https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2016/06/20/passing-t-sql-select-statement-to-sp_execute_external_script/)):

```
 CREATE TABLE #Table1
    (
        [StrCol] NVARCHAR( 50 ),
        [IntCol] INT
    );

    INSERT INTO
        #Table1
        (
            [StrCol],
            [IntCol]
        )
        VALUES
        ( N'testing data 1', 1 ),
        ( N'testing data 2', 2 )
    ;

 CREATE TABLE #Table2
    (
        [StrCol] NVARCHAR( 50 ),
        [IntCol] INT
    );

    INSERT INTO
        #Table2
        (
            [StrCol],
            [IntCol]
        )
        VALUES
        ( N'more testing data 1', 5 ),
        ( N'more testing data 2', 6 )
    ;
```

From here, you can create [VARBINARY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql) types to hold the serialized results translated in R.

```
DECLARE
    @Table1_Input NVARCHAR( MAX ) = 'SELECT * FROM #Table1;',
    @Table2_Input NVARCHAR( MAX ) = 'SELECT * FROM #Table2;',
    @Table1_Data VARBINARY( MAX ),
    @Table2_Data VARBINARY( MAX );

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R',
    @script = N'

        if( nrow(InputDataSet) == 0 )
            stop("Invalid data passed in")

        # Read in the sql table, serialize it to an output string
        Output <- serialize(InputDataSet, NULL)
    ',
    @input_data_1 = @Table1_Input,
    @params = N'@Output VARBINARY( MAX ) OUTPUT',
    @Output = @Table1_Data OUTPUT;

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R',
    @script = N'

        if( nrow(InputDataSet) == 0 )
            stop("Invalid data passed in")

        # Read in the sql table, serialize it to an output string
        Output <- serialize(InputDataSet, NULL)
    ',
    @input_data_1 = @Table2_Input,
    @params = N'@Output VARBINARY( MAX ) OUTPUT',
    @Output = @Table2_Data OUTPUT;
```

Finally,

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R',
    @script = N'

        table1 <- unserialize(Table1_Data)
        table2 <- unserialize(Table2_Data)

        OutputDataSet <- rbind(table1, table2)
    ',
    @params = N'@Table1_Data VARBINARY(MAX), @Table2_Data VARBINARY(MAX)',
    @Table1_Data = @Table1_Data,
    @Table2_Data = @Table2_Data
    WITH RESULT SETS (( [Col1] NVARCHAR( 50 ), [Col2] INT ));
```

Results:

```
Col1    Col2
testing data 1
testing data 2
more testing data 5
more testing data 6
```

Comment: is it possible to pass those tables in JSON format?

Comment: @Eralper which tables? The ones into the SP or the ones into R?

Comment: I mean into R... I think we can easily convert the table data into JSON in SQL Server 2016 and 2017, and then pass these values as string into R. Then we should use an R library to convert back into tabular form. Am I right?

Comment: I'm sure you could, but I don't see the need? Using Binary Serialization is more efficient and you're not as constrained on the output size (as apposed to using a VARCHAR( MAX ) with JSON). See my point?

Comment: Nice solution. Best I've found so far.

Comment: Thank you @Craig!

Comment: Hi @BrandonMoretz can we pass three or more tables? and also my results are not dataframe instead is a boolean value, how to do the same.

Comment: @Shubh You can use this method to pass as many tables as you'd like. In your case in your sounds like you could either 1.) create a dataframe with columns for your booleans, or more crudely, pass a serialized vector and pull them out using 
ordinally.