# sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R'

Tags: r, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

How can we -  Create two Input data set that will be referenced in @Script

Example

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R' 
    , @script = N' OutputDataset <- inputDataSet' 
    , @input_data_1 = N'' 
    , @input_data_2 = N'' -- This line.
    , @input_data_1_name = N'inputDataSet' 
    , @output_data_1_name = N'OutputDataset'
  WITH RESULT SETS ((plot NVARCHAR(max)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use @params if you want more than one input/output. Then you assign the data to a parameter of the exact same name right after it.

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R' 
    , @script = N'
        notUsedAgain <- secondDataSet;
         OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet
         ' 
    , @input_data_1 = N'' 
    , @params = N'@secondDataSet int'
    , @secondDataSet = 1
  WITH RESULT SETS ((plot NVARCHAR(max)));
```

Comment: Can we populate secondDataSet using a query from input_data_2

Comment: Looks like it's not super happy about that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918990/how-to-pass-two-sql-tables-as-input-parameter-for-r-codes-in-sql-server