# Multiple input sources for MSSQL Server 2017 Python analytical services

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am currently porting some code from Spark to the MSSQL Analytical Services with Python. Everything is nice and dandy, but I am not sure if my solution is the correct one for multiple inputs for the scripts.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SampleModel;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SampleModel
AS
BEGIN
exec sp_execute_external_script  
@language =N'Python',
@script=N'
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\path\to\custom\package")

from super_package.sample_model import run_model

OutputDataSet = run_model()'
WITH RESULT SETS ((Score float));
END
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleModelPredictions] (prediction) EXEC [dbo].[SampleModel]
GO
```

I have a custom package called `super_package` and a sample model called `sample_model`. Since this model uses multiple database tables as input, and I would rather have everything in one place I have a module which connects to the database and fetches the data directly:

```
def go_go_get_data(query, config):
    return rx_data_step(RxSqlServerData(
        sql_query=query,
        connection_string=config.connection_string,
        user=config.user,
        password=config.password))
```

Inside the `run_model()` function I fetch all necessary data from the database with the `go_go_get_data` function.

If the data is too big to handle in one go I would to some pagination.
In general I cannot join the tables so this solution doesn't work.
The questions is: Is this the right approach to tackle this problem? Or did I miss something? For now this works, but as I am still in the development / tryout phase I cannot be certain that this will scale. I would rather use the parameters for the stored procedure than fetching inside the Python context.

Comment: Hi @muma! When you say "In general I cannot join the tables so this solution doesn't work," do you mean that you can't join tables inside Python or that it doesn't work to set the `@input_data_1` parameter of `sp_execute_external_script` to a query that contains a join?

Comment: Both, neither inside the Python script nor in the `@input_data_1` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already figured out, `sp_execucte_external_script` only allows one result set to be passed in. :-(

You can certainly query from inside the script to fetch data as long as your script is okay with the fact that it's not executing under the current SQL session's user's permissions.

If pagination is important and one data set is significantly larger than the others *and you're using Enterprise Edition*, you might consider passing the largest data set into the script in chunks using `sp_execute_external_script`'s streaming feature.

If you'd like all of your data to be assembled in SQL Server (vs. fetched by queries in your script), you could try to [serialize the result sets and then pass them in as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426706/117424) (link describes how to do this in R but something similar should be possible with Python).